# iOS, orientationchanges, fires in iOS 5 but not in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have an app that presents a UIWebview modally using presentViewController.
Now the root view supports orientation changes and rotates accordingly. I listen to the event UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification.

Now I present the modal window using "

```
                 presentViewController:navController
                  animated:YES
                completion:nil];
```

I dismiss using

```
                dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

now to the issue : 
in iOS 6, this works fine and the modal window shows up in whatever orientation its parent was in.

in iOS 5 , the presentViewController or dismissModalViewControllerAnimated forcibly throws

UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification!!

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Try using this orientation notification instead:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

Comment: I am already responding to UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification.

Comment: plus I tried subscribing to that notification, still didn't fix the issue!!